# PHP "this" context in anonymous function

Tags: php

I'm trying to call the "this" context within my anonymous function, called inside an object.
I'm running PHP 5.5.9 and the php doc states that "$this can be used in anonymous functions."
What's missing? Should I inject the context in some way binding the function to the object?

```
<?php

class Example
{
    public function __construct()
    {}

    public function test($func)
    {
        $func();
    }
}

$obj = new Example();

$obj->test(function(){
    print_r($this);
});

?>
```

Output:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: this on line 18
```

Comment: I know this question is a bit old but may I know where in the docs has it been stated so that: "$this can be used in anonymous functions."? I've encountered this and I wanted to verify it from the docs but found nothing, then found your question using Google. Is it really in the official documentation?

Comment: [On some crazy languages page](http://docs.php.net/manual/tw/functions.anonymous.php) YES

Answer (score 2):

Well, you actually *can* use `$this` in an anonymous function. *But* you cannot use it outside of an object, that does not make sense. Note  that you define that anonymous function outside your class definition. So what is `$this` mean to be in that case?

A simple solution would be to either define the function inside the class definition or to hand over the `$this` pointer to the function as an argument.

Comment: You can also define using the   function name use (&$obj) { /*code */ }

Comment: I didn't get what you meant with  (&$obj) { /*code */ }. May you please provide an example?

Comment: I was dreaming about the php engine auto passing the right context basing upon where the function was called. But I realized right now how this would be a stupid and error prone thing... you're right!

Answer (score 0):

Solved with this... it definitely horrify me, any other solution (if exists) is well accepted.

```
<?php

class Example
{
    public function __construct()
    {}

    public function test($func)
    {
        $func = $func->bindTo($this, $this);
        $func();
    }
}

$obj = new Example();

$obj->test(function(){
    print_r($this);
});

?>
```

Comment: "any other solution (if exists) is well accepted" - depends on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Im' trying to use "$this" within an anonymous function without calling any closure method prior to it.

Comment: Then the answer is probably "no". But what are you trying to achieve by using $this that way? You might interpret bindTo() as a way of dependency injection, so DI in general might be an option.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be to have $this as an argument of the function, and you just pass it via the call within your class `$func($this)`.

```
<?php

class Example {
    …
    public function test($func)
    {
        $func($this);
    }
}

$obj = new Example();
$obj->test(function($this) {
    print_r($this);
});

?>
```

Comment: Right, passing the scope explicitly as the first parameter is a possibility.